# Valve graffiti - riddle

Tags: riddle

> My first is the most common
>   My second is another $\pi$
>   My third represents Iceland
>   My fourth is indefinite
>   My fifth is potassium hydroxide

Where can you find my whole? And why?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is an old meme: **The cake is a lie**.

> **My first is the most common** word of the English language, which is "the".
>
> **My second is another pi**(e), which is something *like* a pie, or a "cake".
>
> **My third represents Iceland** by being the [ISO 3166-1 alpha2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) country code for it: "is".
>
> **My fourth is** the **indefinite** article "a".
>
> **My fifth is potassium hydroxide**, also known as "lye". Slightly different spelling, but they're pronounced the same, which I think is good enough.
>
> My whole is a piece of graffiti found in the game *Portal*, by Valve.

Comment: Okay, yeah, this answer is definitely way better (by which I mean "obviously correct").

Comment: I admit I was wondering when I first saw the puzzle whether the title was a reference to *that* Valve.

Comment: Huh! That ISO3166-1 list is interesting. I wonder if there are any other puzzles here that reference it.

Comment: @BaileyM: I wouldn't be surprised ISO 3166-1 is the standard used to define top-level domains for countries.

Comment: That wouldn't surprise me, either. The two letter codes are so unassuming, I also wouldn't be surprised if somewhere someone used them as a step in a cryptogram.

Answer (score 12):

Okay here goes.

I'm going out of order because this riddle comes with the "liars" tag, so I'm guessing the teller is lying about first second etc.

> My fifth is potassium hydroxide - **KOH** (abbrev. for potassium hydroxide)
> My second is an other π - **TAO** (Tau is often argued as being a "better" pi. I know I misspelled it, bear with me)
> My third represent Iceland - **ISL** (The 3-letter abbreviation for Iceland)
> My fourth is indefinite - **AN** ("an" is an indefinite article in English grammar)
> My first is the most common - **D** (I'm not sure on this one, but Vitamin D is the most common vitamin deficiency in the world. Which fits with the whole phrase, which is...
>
>  [KOH TAO ISLAND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ko_Tao)

Comment: Nope, that's not it. I'm typing up the solution as we speak.

Comment: Haha your answer better be close, because otherwise this is a pretty crazy coincidence!

Comment: I'll be honest, I sort of saw it about 10 seconds after I read the riddle description. I just got lucky. :P

Comment: So the "liars" tag was just a clue after all!? This is nevertheless a nice creative answer!

Comment: That's very creative. +1

Comment: I think I like this better than the correct answer.